# Why does this javascript work on firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

This is a javascript for a virtual keyboard. Click [here](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard) for the source.

To use this keyboard all i have to do is use a CSS class in the TextBox control. Here is the TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFTP" SkinID="Mini2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
ForeColor="Gray" CssClass="keyboardInputCenter txtAllign" />
```

Jquery references are in the master page.

```
<script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/keyboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My aspx page "XYZ.aspx" runs ok in firefox and the virtual keyboard pops up when the textbox is clicked but in chrome for the same form nothing happens.

**I have used the same script to show a virtual keyboard and that works for both firefox and chrome but that page and master page is in another folder.**

**How can i fix/work around this?**

Comment: link works for me in Chrome/OSX

Comment: @ahren keyboard worked in a page for chrome but it doesn't work in the rest of the pages for chrome(works in firefox).... Pages that are unable to show the keyboard are in another folder but all of the links are ok......

Comment: And are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Visual studio doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Visual Studio != Google chrome. Since we're talking javascript, we're talking about the javascript console.

Comment: @ahren .... my bad! ..... No there are no errors in console but some non-related image conversion warnings.

Comment: what about any files missing? See either the network panel or resources for red links/404s

Comment: @ahren ..... no missing files/red links... all of the links are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. There was a  "div" that wasn't closed. Somehow firefox worked with that error but Chrome/IE didn't. If you know why firefox worked please leave a comment. Thank you all for your cooperation.

Comment: Firefox detects the unclosed tags and close them for you, that's simply it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the java script is enabled in firefox . Some times some code will run in chrome  but not in firefox because the web-kit engine is different